# \r\n Replace not working while sending Emails using PhpMailer Library

Tags: php, preg-replace, phpmailer

I have been trying to send emails, using the PHP Mail Library and have been partially successful.
The only problem that I am facing is, when the Mail is received by the receiver, every new line is shown as \r\n .
I have tried this:

```
$body = str_replace("\\r\\n", '\n', $body);
```

but it shows a '\n' instead of a new line.
I have also tried this:

```
$body = str_replace("\\r\\n", "\\n", $body);
```

but it shows nothing but a blank space. No new lines still :( 
 
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "shown as \r\n"? Are there two line breaks? Or the literal characters?

Comment: \r\n denotes a line break when you take input from a text area. They are displayed as Literal Characters

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be:

```
$body = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $body);
```

Your first example was almost right, apart from that you had \n inside single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Blockquote$body = stripcslashes(isset($body) ? preg_replace(' (\\r|\\r\\n|\\n)#', '
> ', $body) : false);
>   $body = str_replace("
> ","
> ",$body);

It works for me